# ASButtonNode attributedTitle for different controlStates

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have a problem with `ASButtonNode` and `attributedTitle` for different control states and using fractional size. The title becomes shifted to the left.

I behaved correctly if I use a point size for the button.

I am running `texture/asyncDisplayKit 2.8.1`.

```swift
/* Set title */
testButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "NORMAL"), for: .normal)
testButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "HIGHLIGHTED"), for: .highlighted)

/* styling */
/** This works
 * testButton.style.width = ASDimensionMake("120pt") 
 **/
testButton.style.width = ASDimensionMake("30%")
testButton.style.height = ASDimensionMake(120)
```

The title should not get shifted to the right after tapping the button. Am I missing something?

**After highlight state**

[image]

**Before highlight state**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can specify the `alignment` on`paragraphStyle`

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

let attributes = [ ... your current style,
                  .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle] as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
]

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "your text here", attributes: attributes)
```

you can create 2 `attributedString` for each state than set it for respective state

```
testButton.setAttributedTitle(normalAttributedString, for: .normal)
testButton.setAttributedTitle(highlightedAttributedString, for: .highlight)
```

*Happy Texturing*